# Question regarding Bertrand's paradox

Tags: probability, geometry, parametrization, paradoxes

The classic example of Bertrand paradox deals with the case where we count the uncountable set of chords in a circle in different ways and ends up getting different probability each time. The wikipedia example shows how we got $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4} $  respectively in different cases.

My question from here is can we always find some, way of choosing the chords so that the probability ends up spanning the whole rational set or even the whole real number set.

What I mean by spanning the whole rational number set $\mathbb{Q}$ is as follows:

> $\forall q \in \mathbb{Q} \text{(}or \mathbb{R}\text{)} \cap [0,1]$ there exist some way of choosing the chord in the circle so that probability in that space becomes $q$?

Comment: This is the exact same question I asked my professor after we learned this in our probability course. But, he couldn't come up with an answer (although he tried quite hard). Later, I realised, the answer is *most probably* negative. You see, the three different cases give three different probabilities because they follow three different models (i.e., three different ways) of choosing a chord randomly- in other words, these three processes define chord in three different ways (to understand this better, check out Grant Sanderson's video on Numberphile, if you haven't already)......

Comment: ..... So, to force the probability to be anything in $\mathbb R\cap [0,1]$, you have to have uncountably many *ways of choosing* (or *ways of defining*) a chord. That demands uncountably many different models. Does this seem possible? Not to me atleast :(  Also, no matter what model you choose, it is intuitively quite clear that the probability can never be $1$ or $0$ (c'mon man, how can it be?). So, even if there is a way to make some more models to force the probability to lie where we want it to, it will have some bounds $a\leq p\leq b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb R\cap(0,1)$.

Comment: It is not an answer to your question but you might find it of interest. There is an approach that yields a different result than the ones you have listed: https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2013_14/math7h_s2014/math7h_s2014_lecture2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with models not very "meaningful" as those on wikipedia, there is always a way: adding a selection step to tilt the weight. Say we have a $\frac 12$-scheme as that described on wiki.

If you want any $p<\frac 12$, you can choose a chord from the $\frac 12$-scheme, and keep it with probability $2p$ while discard it with probability $(1-2p)$. This gives you a scheme with success rate $p$.

If you want $p>\frac 12$, you can let $q=2-\frac 1p\in(0,1)$ and do the following. If you get a successful chord, keep it. Otherwise you discard the unsuccessful chord with probability $q$ and select again. The overall success rate is now

$$\frac 12+\frac 12\cdot q\cdot\frac 12+\frac 12\cdot q\cdot\frac 12\cdot q\cdot\frac 12+\cdots=\frac 12\cdot\frac{1}{1-q/2}=p,$$

as desired.